# Game project p5.js / javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am experiencing an issue with a game project using p5.js and when my character loses all the lives ,it prints negative numbers for ever and when the character reaches to end point for the game to be complete , the player still interacts . I am trying to do 2 things , I am trying to make the character when falls down on the canvas lose 3 lives and then to show a text that is a game over and restart the game from where was. The second is when my character is reached to the end point for the game to be complete , to show with text " game complete" and when I press a key from a keyboard to restart as well as the previous. Anyone could help me please . Thank you

```js
if( lives < 0)
    {
        fill('red');
        textSize(30);
        text("Game Over . Press space to continue" , width/4 , height);
        return;
    }
    
    
if( flagpole.isReached === true )
{
   fill('red');
   textSize(30);
   text("Level Complete. Press space to continue", width/4 , height);
   return;
}



function checkPlayerDie()
{   
    if(gameChar_y > height)
    {
        lives -= 1;

      if(lives > 0)
      {
        startGame();
      }

    }`enter code here`
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow. You're asking a few different things and it's hard to help with all of them at once so I'll do my best to address how you can organize this more generally.

The logic of your code is a good start and makes sense but it doesn't address/solve all that you're trying to achieve. For example, your code does check for lives being less than 0 (aka dead), but I don't see you calling a function to stop or reset the game to the beginning. That's why the lives continues to tick down in the negative.

A minimal lose() function might for example also print "sorry you lose" on screen, reset lives to 0, and play a sound. That might look like this:

```
function loseGame(){
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  text("Sorry, you lose. Try again", 10, 10);
  lives = 0;
  loseSound.play(); //note, you'd have to load this in preload() earlier
}
```

The kind of structure that could help you is called a *finite state machine*. This sounds complicated, but it just basically means, what is the logic underlying your game's state? Many people making games draw out a diagram of the flow of their game (start screen, playing, lose, win, etc) and how one moves between those states. It's common for beginners to code a function for each of their states with the full functionality needed.

To learn more about working with sound in p5.js, check out the [soundFile](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.SoundFile) reference for an example.